# POSTMAN Visualizers: <script> tags in templates for Tests script not working

Tags: testing, postman, visualizer

I am trying to create a very simple Tests script, which can display response text. Here my <span> tag works fine, but I don’t get the console log in <script> tag. The console log outside the template works fine, also if I save the template contents as HTML, it prints the <script> tag console log. But it is not working with POSTMAN. Please help in the resolution.

My Tests script contents are as below.

```
var template = `

<script>console.log('test in template');</script>

<span style="white-space: pre-line">{{result}}</span>

`;

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

result = jsonData.result

console.log('test: in test');

pm.visualizer.set(template, {

// Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `data`

result: result
});
```

Thanks,
prasanna

Comment: It wouldn't log that in the same place, as it's not the same thing. Right-click on the visualiser, to inspect it. You will see the console logs there.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Danny Dainton is correct. I was missing the knowledge that POSTMAN console and Visualization console is different. As I right-clicked on the visualizer Area, got the option for "Inspect Visualization", which opens the browser devtools/F12 window with all the options.

Thank you Danny.

Comment: Would you put a quote of the comment in your answer for completeness?